# C# datagridview compare cell values of every row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Will try to explain this as clear as i can.

I have a datagridview. I have 3 rows and 7 cells. On the 7th cell there is stored a DateTimePicker value. I want to compare value of 7th cell of every row with some date. If the date value of 7th cell is higher than date that i want it to compare to, color the row in red color.

I went this far:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  if( dont know what to type here) 
      {
         r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract out the 7th Cell `Value` and convert/cast it to `DateTime` then you can compare it like: *(remember cells are 0 based, so 7th cell would be at `r.Cells[6]`)*

```
DateTime yourCompareDate = DateTime.Now;
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DateTime cellValue7 = Convert.ToDateTime(r.Cells[6].Value); //Convert/Cast value to date
    if(cellValue7 > yourCompareDate)
    {
        r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var compareDate = DateTime.Now; //or whatever date you want
foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
      var cellDate = Convert.TodateTime(r.Cells[6].Value); 
      if (cellDate > compareDate) r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;    
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        DateTime dtValue = DateTime.Now;  // You Date Time Value
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((DateTime)r.Cells[6].Value > dtValue)
            {
                r.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the general idea, but please put more specific details.  By that I mean keep in mind that the question asked about finding DateTimes that were higher than the value.